# My PYTHONPATH env doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, pip

I've installed pip on my computer(mac), and I tried these:

```
$export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip
$python pip freeze list
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It doesn't work, but if I specify this full path into python command, it works:

```
$python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip freeze list
ant==0.1.0
appnope==0.1.0
astroid==1.4.8
backports-abc==0.5
........
```

Why is that?

Comment: Why are you changing the PYTHONPATH at all?

Comment: PYTHONPATH affects how the Python interpreter will resolve references for `import` statements.  It doesn't affect which Python interpreter will be involved nor how the shell will resolve references to executables (such as your `pip` script).  I turns out that Python's `import` semantics are considerably more complicated that most people realize even after years of Python experience.  Here's are some hints: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `pip freeze` directly should be sufficient. You shouldn't have to run it via `python pip` or tweak `$PYTHONPATH` at all.

The error in that first snippet has to do with how you are invoking python. Your command is interpreted as `python <script-filename> [script-arguments ...]`. The filename you are passing in is `pip`, so python looks for a file named "pip" in the current directory. That file does not exist, so python crashes with a "file not found" error.

`python <full-path-to-script>` works because... well, why wouldn't it? Python finds the script and executes it.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments you don't want to mess around with PYTHONPATH. If you want to have different versions of python on the same computer or python installations with different installed packages (or modules) what you need is to use [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)

Create a new virtualenv.

```
virtualenv /usr/local/custom-python/
```

and then whenever you want to use it or install packages into it, just do

```
source /usr/local/custom-python/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use:
`$export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
Firstly, your code may cover the orignal PYTHONPATH which is deprecated. Secondly, do not include pip into the python path because pip is a package that should be included.

`python /your/path/to/pip` this pip is a folder in which there is a `__init__.py` . So python can read it. But if you directly define PYTHONPATH to pip folder, python will not find this `__init__.py` to represent pip (See document about python import packge)

Besides, I think you can include the binary pip (may located /usr/bin) in  into your path so that you can call it directly with `$ pip command`